# Improved version of FindFaces

Tags: computer-vision

The built-in function `FindFaces` seems to miss faces a lot, for example

```
i = Import@"https://celebritiesindisgrace.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/2014-oscar-twitter-pic-600x308.jpg";
HighlightImage[i, {"Boundary", Green, Rectangle @@@ FindFaces[#] &}]
```

[image]

Are there other mma implementations of face detection to use?

Comment: Note that this is not the fault of the function itself. All Faces not detected are just partially visible. Every Face fully visible is detected.

Comment: I believe that question to be a duplicate, even though you've posed a slightly different question. I honestly cannot understand how you could fail to mention that post in your question.

Comment: I don't believe it's a duplicate. I don't want to replace the cascade, I looking for different methods entirely

Comment: @M.R. could you elaborate on 'entirely different method' and methods you've found?

Comment: Any net related solution that doesn't rely on handcrafted features...

Comment: Anything more robust then a cascade with sift or hog or lbp